# Cannot get latitude and longtidute with CoreLocation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I want to get the coordinates of the user, once user starts the app it should initialise GPS coordinates. I have followed this tutorial:
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/ios-corelocation-tutorial/

I have created a class named CurrentLocationWithGPS

This is the header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CurrentLocationWithGPS : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void) getLocations;

- (Float32) latitude;


@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end
```

This is the implementation:

```
#import "CurrentLocationWithGPS.h"


@implementation CurrentLocationWithGPS

@synthesize locationManager, currentLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) { [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if(error.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    } else if(error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
        // retry
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error retrieving location"
                                                        message:[error description]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (void) getLocations {
    NSLog(@"GPS Location is initialising...");

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"GPS Location is initialised...");

}

- (Float32) latitude {

    return currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
}

- (Float32) longitude {

    return currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}

@end
```

I call the getLocations function in a separate thread so that it wouldn't block anything else. Here is how I call it from another class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(locationSet) object:nil];
    [myThread start];

}

- (void) locationSet {

    CurrentLocationWithGPS *locationFind = [[CurrentLocationWithGPS alloc] init];
    locationFind.getLocations;
    NSLog(@"latitude is %f", locationFind.latitude);
}
```

Now the problem is both `latitude` and `longitdute` functions are returning 0.000, what am I missing here? I am developing for iOS6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First conforms `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in **.h** file like this

```
@interface CurrentLocationWithGPS : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

You need to set CLLocation's Delegate in this method.

```
- (void) getLocations
 {
    NSLog(@"GPS Location is initialising...");

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"GPS Location is initialised...");
}
```

Comment: @SarpKaya Now what problem you are getting... ?

Comment: Same problem. I am getting latitude and longitude as 0.0000

Comment: See my edited answer and why are you calling locationSet on thread n all these thing you can do in viewDidLoad method. No need to make more complecity...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think i was missing that two lines of         locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; and 
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

Answer (score 0):

Do you getting the Current Location on the output . Or  R you just trying to retrieve the Co-ordinates  ?..

It's still confusing , anyhow

Put this part of code on Your `getLocations` method

> I Hope that You are not at all checking with Location Services . You
>   Should enable the LocationServices for your app else You always get
>   null values Check with the Condition:

```
 if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
}
```

For Example :

```
       CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }

        location = [locationManager location];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];;
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
```

And Let me know , .????